# Metedo $_POST[] no funciona

Tags: php, html

amigos tengo un error extrañísimo, estoy haciendo una prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="enviar/ejemplo.php" method="post">
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y en el otro archivo ejemplo.php:

```
<html>
  <body>
     Hola <?php echo $_POST["nombre"]; ?><br>
     Tu email es: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

entonces al tipearlo desde mi chrome y rellenar los datos, al presionar el submit me muestra esto:

```
<html>
<body>
Hola <?php echo $_POST["nombre"]; ?><br>
Tu email es: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

realmente no entiendo y lo peor es que llevo toda la tarde en esto.... al parecer no se esta enviando la informacion.

Comment: Te muestra literalmente las etiquetas y el código PHP? Qué servidor estás usando para probar esos archivos?

Comment: Exacto!!! literalmente!!!! estoy usando Wampserver

Comment: Yo acabo de reproducir el código que dejaste y se muestra perfecto. Uso Xampp, pero no debiese ser el servidor el problema... aunque quien sabe si hay una configuración mala.

Comment: Pues eso pasa cuando no estás usando el servidor para interpretar el código PHP. Revisa que tus archivos estén en una carpeta servida por wamp y revisa que en tu navegador hayas abierto `http://localhost/ruta/a/tu/archivo.php` y no algo como `file://C:/ruta/al/archivo.php`

Comment: Fijate en el conf de Apache que `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html` incluya a archivos `.php`

Comment: ya consegui la solucion, tal cual menciono Ororok era problema de configuracion del archivo phpmyadmin ubicado en el direccorio C:\wamp\alias, cambie la ultima linea de codigo, la linea estaba "Allow from 127.0.0.1" y lcambie a "Allow from all" y l alinea "Order allow,deny" la elimine.

Comment: @GersonAriasCardenas en la comunidad no ponemos SOLUCIONADO a las publicaciones cuando ya tienen una respuesta que solucione el problema, alcanza con colocarla en el espacio de respuestas y eventualmente marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Solucion

dirigirse al direcctorio-> C:\wamp\alias y abrir el archivo "phpmyadmin" y en la ultima linea del archivo eliminar la linea "Order allow,deny" y en la linea "Allow from 127.0.0.1" cambiar a  "Allow from all"